# HTML code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This HTML is not working for some reason...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Gallery</title>
        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gallery.css"/>
        Note: use if stylesheet is separated from main project
        I am embedding the CSS so it is easier to send
        -->
        <!--
        <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery.js"></script>
        Note: use if javascript is separated from main project
        I am embedding the JS so it is easier to send
        -->
        <style>
            /* CSS */
            #topbar {}
            #selection {border: 3pt solid red;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Javascript
        </script>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topbar">
            <table id="selection">
                <tr>
                    <td>Test1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nothing in the `body` shows up! I even tried sticking a random `<p>` in there with some text and it didn't show up. What is the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to close your `<script>` tag. Self closing tags are not valid with the `<script>` element:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: oh, silly me. thanks! I'll accept the answer when stack overflow lets me.

Comment: “Self closing tags” are valid (as you can see by using http://validator.w3.org on the document), they just don’t work (they are recognized simply as start tags), because XHTML documents are actually processed by HTML rules in browsers (unless sent with an XML content type, which makes IE choke). This is why the Compatibility Guidelines in XHTML 1.0 advice against them: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines